# Firebase notification history and tracking a notification

Tags: php, android, firebase

Is it possible to see the notifications history?
As far as I know, I can see only the notifications that created by the **Firebase console**. As shown here

[image: screenshot].

I send many notifications with PHP script with `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` , which works fine, but not listing that notifications here.

How can I list the sent notifications in the Firebase console?

Answer (score 2):

With Firebase support ticket, I go the following:

> You could see the statistics and delivery reports for notifications sent through **FCM API** (App Server) for a published Google Play app in your **Google Play Developer Console**.
>   [This article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268) explains it in detail.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this bro! It will help a lot.